# Reusing Dataclass Type Hints

Tags: python, python-3.x, alias, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to reuse type hints from a dataclass in my function signature - that is, without having to type the signature out again.

What would be the best way of going about this?

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Set, Tuple, Type

@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    force: Set[Tuple[str, float, bool]]

# I've had to write the same type annotation in the dataclass and the
# function signature - yuck
def do_something(force: Set[Tuple[str, float, bool]]):
    print(force)

# I want to do something like this, where I reference the type annotation from
# the dataclass. But, doing it this way, pycharm thinks `force` is type `Any`
def do_something_2(force: Type["MyDataClass.force"]):
    print(force)
```

Comment: You can't do that. You can use a type-alias, though, `GoodName =  Set[Tuple[str, float, bool]]` and just re-use that, `GoodName`

Comment: Also, this really has nothing to do with dataclasses

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the type-alias idea. I am hoping to avoid having to create auxiliary variables like that, but yeah it certainly is a solution. And yeah this has nothing to do with dataclasses, just convenient for illustrating the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What would be the best way of going about this?

PEP 484 gives one clear option for this case

> [Type aliases](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-aliases)
>
> Type aliases are defined by simple variable assignments:
> (...)
> Type aliases may be as complex as type hints in annotations -- anything that is acceptable as a type hint is acceptable in a type alias:

Applied to your example this would amount to (Mypy confirms this as correct)

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

Your_Type = set[tuple[str, float, bool]]


@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    force: Your_Type


def do_something(force: Your_Type):
    print(force)
```

The above is written using Python 3.9 onward [Generic Alias Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#generic-alias-type). The syntax is more concise and modern since [typing.Set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Set) and [typing.Tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple) have been deprecated.

---

---

Now, fully understanding this in terms of the [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) is more complicated than it may seem:

> [3.1. Objects, values and types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types)
>
> Every object has an identity, a type and a value.

Your first attempt of using `Type` would give an astonishing result

```py
>>> type(MyDataClass.force)

AttributeError: type object 'MyDataClass' has no attribute 'force'
```

This is because the builtin function `type` returns a type (which is itself an object) but `MyDataClass` is "a Class" (a declaration) and the "Class attribute" `force` is on the Class not on the type object of the class where `type()` looks for it. Notice the Data Model carefully on the difference:

> - Classes
>
>   These objects normally act as factories for new instances of themselves
> - Class Instances
>
>   Instances of arbitrary classes

If instead you checked the type on an instance you would get the following result

```py
>>> init_values: set = {(True, "the_str", 1.2)}

>>> a_var = MyDataClass(init_values)

>>> type(a_var)
<class '__main__.MyDataClass'>

>>> type(a_var.force)
<class 'set'>
```

Now lets recover the type object (not the type hints)  on `force` by applying `type()` to the [`__anotations__`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-annotation) on the Class declaration object (here we see the [Generic Alias type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#generic-alias-type) mentioned earlier). (Here we are indeed checking the type object on the class attribute `force`).

```py
>>> type(MyDataClass.__annotations__['force'])
<class 'typing._GenericAlias'>
```

Or we could check the annotations on the Class instance, and recover the type hints as we are used to seeing them.

```py
>>> init_values: set = {(True, "the_str", 1.2)}
>>> a_var = MyDataClass(init_values)
>>> a_var.__annotations__

{'force': set[tuple[str, float, bool]]}
```

> I've had to write the same type annotation in the dataclass and the function signature -

For tuples annotations tend to become long literals and that justifies creating a purpose variable for conciseness. But in general explicit signatures are more descriptive and it's what most API's go for.

> [The `typing` Module](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-typing-module)
>
> Fundamental building blocks:
>
> Tuple, used by listing the element types, for example `Tuple[int, int, str]`. The empty tuple can be typed as `Tuple[()]`. Arbitrary-length homogeneous tuples can be expressed using one type and ellipsis, for example `Tuple[int, ...]`. (The ... here are part of the syntax, a literal ellipsis.)

Comment: absolutely very cool and insightful, thanks!